# How to re-write with Bayes' Rule as a function?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability, naive-bayes

I'm a little bit stuck. Say I have a P(A | B ^ C). How could I re-write this as a function with the terms P(B|A ^ C), P(B|C) and P(C|B) and can anyone explain how this was done?

Comment: In some sense, $P$ is a function already, so it is unclear what you mean. (The sense is that $P$ is a function from the sigma algebra of events to the interval $[0,1]$. This perhaps is not along the lines of what you mean. And if this doesn’t make any sense, it’s okay not to do measure-theoretic probability the first few times you study the subject.)

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated. Note that you can use LaTeX markup in questions and answers here. You can thus make your question more readable by using dollar signs around your formulas. Moreover, do not forget to mark answers as accepted so that a thread can be considered closed. Concerning the question, there might be a typo and you presumably mean $P(A|C)$ instead of $P(C|B)$ (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

To write $P(A|B\cap C)$ in terms of $P(B|A\cap C)$, you can use the definition of the conditional probability:
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Applying this defintion to $P(A|B\cap C)$ and $P(B|A\cap C)$ leads to the same term $P(B \cap A\cap C)$ in the numerator, which you can thus substitute:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(A|B\cap C) & = & \frac{P(B|A\cap C)\cdot P(A\cap C)}{P(B\cap C)} \\
& = & \frac{P(B|A\cap C)\cdot P(A|C)\cdot P(C)}{P(B|C)\cdot P(C)} \\
& = & \frac{P(B|A\cap C)\cdot P(A|C)}{P(B|C)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I do not see, though, how you can further substitute $P(A|C)$ with $P(C|B)$.